# Parse Google plus one count using http://share.yandex.ru/gpp.xml?

Tags: regex, json

This is a link
http://share.yandex.ru/gpp.xml?url=http://www.bloggerever.com/

It shows the number of plus one count for http://bloggerever.com, I want to parse the numbers of plus one count.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access other domains via `$.getJSON` due to the same origin policy. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain) question for details.

Comment: I will appreciate if you will give some code to parse the number of plus one count

Answer (score 0):

The response is JavaScript so you can actually access the value like this.

```
<script>
window.services = {
    gplus: {
        cb: function(plus1) {
            alert(plus1);
        }
    }
}
</script>
<script src="https://share.yandex.ru/gpp.xml?url=http://www.bloggerever.com/" async></script>
```

Be aware that loading arbitrary JavaScript on your site remove all security precautions for whoever controls that JS.